# Apache2 Virtual Host Proxy Forward

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy

Hi all I am trying to use a virtual host to forward streaming.fusion.tk to my internal emby server form my webserver.

I have setup a config file called streaming.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName streaming.fusion.tk
ServerAdmin fusion@localhost

ProxyRequests off
<Proxy "*">
Order deny, allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.203:8096/
ProxyPassReverse / http:192.168.0.203:8096/

</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled the site using sudo nano a2ensite streaming.conf and restarted the apache2 service

When I try and get to the site I am not able to access anything.

Some help would be appriciated.

Comment: Your site seems to be working fine. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: `sudo nano a2ensite streaming.conf` shouldn't contain `nano`

Comment: you're also missing `//` in `ProxyPassReverse / http:192.168.0.203:8096/`

Comment: @MichaelHampton thats just my main page for fusion.tk.

Comment: @tomasz I may of typed that by accednet.  I missed that thanks. But it is still not showing up. 

I am lost to why this does not work. Spent all day yesterday working on this :(

Comment: Neither `ProxyRequests` nor the entire `<Proxy>` block should be there at all. It looks like you pasted those out of a bad Internet tutorial. Anyway your site now gives a 403 error, so what is the current state of the configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can get to the sites when using the IP address with in my local network or when I use my public IP and Port. 

Yes I did follow a tutorial from he web. But most show the same thing.

If I remove the ProxyRequest and <Proxy> Block and now I get the Forbidden message on my phone, Using the OPTUS network.

Comment: `<VirtualHost *>
      ServerName streaming.fusion.tk
        ServerAdmin fusion@outlook.com
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.203:8096/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.203:8096/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>'

Comment: What is in the error log, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton

From the log file when working on it this morning. 

Sun Aug 15 20:25:17.754330 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 21105] [client 49.197.169.197:61669] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://192.168.0.203:8096/
[Sun Aug 15 20:31:36.185761 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 21106] [client 44.193.78.119:49868] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://azenv.net/
[Sun Aug 15 21:48:48.736434 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 21109] [client 76.118.17.84:33424] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://192.168.0.203:8096/

Answer (score 1):

I edited my streaming.conf file and added the bellow

```
<Proxy http://192.168.0.203:8096>
Require all granted
Options None
</Proxy>
```

and now I am able to access streaming.fusion.tk